# Can anyone explain me how to solve the error in installing homebrew in macbook running mavericks?

Tags: git, macos, terminal, homebrew

I tried installing homebrew using the ruby command found in homebrew home page. But I repeatedly failed to do. I get error as follows.

```
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
remote: Counting objects: 209149, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (56183/56183), done.
error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200 MiB | 77.00 KiB/s    
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n
```

I searched for it and I found one suggested solution, i.e, changing buffer size using the command

```
 git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

But when I run this command I get

```
error: could not lock config file .git/config: No such file or directory
```

I dont know how to solve this issue. In some posts i found people asking for the report by running the command

```
git remote -v
```

but when i do that i get

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I wasted one day fully exploring all possible means. Kindly anyone help me to install homebrew.

Comment: Try and do a git remote add origin http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git from your git repo.Then do a git remote -v

Comment: I was successful with the ruby command, when I tried after a day. So the problem was in the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to install it as explained [here](http://brew.sh/), that means by running:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Or by some reason you need the source code?

Comment: In the end I installed HomeBrew by following the instructions here:https://medium.com/macoclock/a-clean-approach-to-installing-homebrew-d17c797fb045

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```